# ExpressJS : Why should I seperate my routes and the functions handling them?

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, express

I've recently started a Nodejs project and my roads look like this :

```
router.get('/groups/', function(req, res) {
  GroupManager.getAllGroup(function(groups) {
    return res.json(groups);
  });
});
```

I saw few example of people separating their routes and the function handling them, leading to something like :

GroupController.js

```
exports.module = {
    getAll : function(fn) {
        GroupManager.getAllGroup(function(groups) {
            fn(groups);
        }
    }
}
```

Routes.js

```
router.get('/groups/', function(req, res) {
  GroupController.getAll(function(groups) {
      return res.json(groups);
  });
});
```

The project I'm starting is growing pretty fast so it's very important for me to have a clean codebase, but I struggle to find the benefit of this way of splitting the code.

Also, I'm struggling trying to find some documentation about code organisation under expressJS. I found many blog post discussing it, but nothing that made authority, is there some famous open-source expressJs project I could use as inspiration ?

Comment: Its not a famous Express project but you can take a look at a starter app I have for basic routing/controller setup if you would like. [node-rethinkdb-auth-starter](https://github.com/drhurdle/node-rethinkdb-auth-starter) .  Use any of it that you would like.  With regards to this question, I think most of the stuff you will find interesting will be in `server.js` and `/server/controllers`.  Not sure if this is 100% the best way, but I have found it to be fairly easy to follow and troubleshoot when I have problems.  Feel free to ask any questions if you have them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Ideally you want separation of concerns, this is probably not the example of showing that but consider the following. The route should be only in charge with routing, not any business logic/operations, other then handing of the task to a function (i.e the controller). The controller should ideally do business logic stuff, and model should ideally only interact with the database.

At this point your controller isn't doing anything other then simply calling fetching the data:

```
   GroupManager.getAllGroup(function(groups) {
        fn(groups);
    }
```

and passing it back. But lets consider the scenario where you wanted the group page to display groups, but also users the top users interacting with the groups. or wanted to send metrcis or really do any manipulation to the groups data from `GroupManager.getAllGroup` i.e

```
   GroupManager.getAllGroup(function(groups) {
        UserManager.getPopularUsers(groups[0], function(users){
             var result = {
                groupId: groups[0].id
                groupName: groups[0].name
                groupPopularUser: user.popularUser
             }
         }

        //do other cimputations that may be needed, may send a metrcis data
     }
```

In your example, the separation isn't really needed but, over time it can be. Of course, this may be too verbose for what you are doing, and you need to decide whether having the extra cost of structuring ahead of time will save time later on when complexity grows.